# Superscript symbols with textcomp

Tags: babel, textcomp

I'm using `babel` `[main=frenchb]` to write my thesis and in some cases I need a star sign in superscript.

With the `textcomp` package I have no problem to get the star sign, but when I use the normal superscript mode (`^{\textborn}`), the star changes into a superscript "b".

How can I get my superscript star?

Comment: What about `$X^\star$`?

Comment: I tried that and it gives no error report but it just doesn't show anything in the outcome document, no star, just a blank...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the symbol in text it is `\textsuperscript{\textborn}`; in math it is `^{\star}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=french]{babel}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

In text it is this\textsuperscript{\textborn}.

In math it is $a^{\star}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the `amsmath` package, it can be achieved by

```
$a^{\text{\textborn}}$.
```

This solution might not be as “clean”, but it will work in other cases as well if you don't know the math equivalent of a `\text...` macro.